# get the sound level in decibels using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to iOS world . I have a doubt . I would like to achieve the dB SPL meter .I have two buttons 1. play song 2. display decibel value . When I click on the Play song button it is playing the song. My question is while playing the sound I have to display the sound value in decibels which comes from iPhone . I have searched in the google . But I am not getting any basic ideas to start this app . Please give me idea to do this . Let me know if my question not clear .

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you exactly mean by "decibel value"?

Comment: I mean I have to display the sound level in decibel units

Comment: [And do you know what that means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure)? How are you going to measure the actual sound pressure? Against what do you want to calibrate your values?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify which framework you are using for playback. But assuming you are using AVFoundation, you could use [AVCaptureAudioChannel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureAudioChannel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureAudioChannel) `averagePowerLevel` or `peakHoldLevel`.

The relevant property for your problem seems to be `averagePowerLevel`, which is (from the docs):

> The instantaneous average power level, in dB. (read-only)

For details, see Apple's AVFoundation Programming Guide, which [includes a section about audio previews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW42).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem could be to convert it from a logarithmic to a linear scale:

```
CGFloar linearScale = powf(10.f, logarithmicScale) * 20.f;
```

where `logarithmicScale` is the value you get from AVFoundation. The linear scale should be much easier to visualize!